# iOS AES decryption not working

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

I am encrypting a file using the following command in Terminal on my Mac

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in testin.txt -out test.txt
```

I am then uploading my file to the web and then downloading it in my iOS app, once the download has finished I am decrypting it.

```
NSString *password = @"myPasswordTextWhichIs32CharsLong";
NSData *decryptedData = [self.testData AES256DecryptWithKey:password];
NSString* decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decrypted string = %@",decryptedStr);
```

I then have a NSData-AES.m file containing:

```
#import "NSData-AES.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData(AES)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

The NSLog for decrypted string returns a different string than in the test.txt so I know some sort of decryption is occurring.

Any ideas where I am going wrong and what needs to be changed.

NOTE: I tried the openssl terminal command without -salt but no different

Comment: How are you actually assigning the password in the first place?  See here for some more info -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271588/decode-openssl-aes256-string-in-ios

Comment: when you put the openssl command in terminal it prompts you to enter the passphrase

Comment: Well, as in the post above, try using the -p command and see if it gives you an IV.